# Can´t access to read properties in array with object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx

i'm using angular+ngrx, but i get a problem, this is output in console

```
{status: true, rows: 1, data: Array(1)}
data: Array(1)
0: {id: "Q", description: "QQQQQ", is_active: true, created_at: "2021-02-05T01:24:21.594Z", updated_at: "2021-02-05T01:24:21.594Z"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
rows: 1
status: true
__proto__: Object
```

but, i can't access to the properties of the object inside of array like id. I defined a interface like this:

```
export interface TipoDocumentoResult {
    status: boolean;
    rows: number;
    data: TipoDocumento
}
```

and TipoDocumento is a class:

```
export class TipoDocumento {
    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public description: string,
        public is_active: boolean,
        public created_at: Date,
        public updated_at: Date,
    ) { }
}
```

This is my ngOnInit:

```
this.store.pipe(
      select('tipoDocumentoGetOne'),
      filter(({ loading, loaded }) => loading === false && loaded === true),     
    ).subscribe(
      ({ data }) => {
        this._result = data
        this._data = this._result?.data
        console.log(this._result)
        console.log(this._data[0]) // Here, i get error message
      }
    );
```

i get this message:

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'TipoDocumento'.
Property '0' does not exist on type 'TipoDocumento'

Sorry, i'm trying to translate in english my problem.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are already destructuring your object in your subscribe:

```
  ({ data }) => { // variable 'data' is already of type TipoDocumento
```

You are basically saying: There is an object coming which has a 'data' field and I'm only interested in that particular field.
If you change the name of 'data' in your subscribe, you should actually get an Compile Error.

I think what you need is actually this:

```
this.store.pipe(
      select('tipoDocumentoGetOne'),
      filter(({ loading, loaded }) => loading === false && loaded === true),     
    ).subscribe(
     result => {
        this._result = result 
        this._data = this._result?.data
        console.log(this._result)
        console.log(this._data[0]) // Here, i get error message
      }
    );
```

And a sidenote to NRGX: Using classes (in your case TipoDocumento) in NGRX Store is risky, since immutability is hard to assure and Helper Frameworks such as NGRX Entity actually break the class into a plain javascript object.